# How to find minimum x coordinate of 3 points using c#

Tags: c#

i have `point1 = [1,2], point2 = [3,5], point3 = [8,10]`
how return `point1` that has minimum x coordinate

```
 Point []p = {
                 new Point(1, 12),  
                 new Point(3, 5),  
                 new Point(8, 10)
             }; 
 findmin(p);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is a basis of max-min algorithm

Comment: yeah i tried with looping all, is there any way to find simple using functions of c#??

Comment: @PR13R can you share the ``Point`` class? is the X and Y are properties or private fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq

```
var minXPoint = p.Min(point => point.X);
```

If you need point object use (O(n)^2)

```
var minPoint = p.OrderBy(point => point .X).FirstOrDefault();
```

or (O(n))

```
var minPoint = p.Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1.X < p2.X ? p1: p2);
```

Comment: @PR13 R The min will return ``1`` not ``(1,2)``. if you want ``1`` change the question!

Comment: @sajid sorry i am looking for point which has 1

Comment: so, the @Yura answer is correct?